# Android Package Name Using Same Word?

Tags: android, package-name

Say I have a company named Moose with an app called Moose.

Is it okay to create a package name like "com.moose.moose"?

Comment: "Is it okay to..." well, have you tried it :) do you maybe have more specific concerns ? just trying to narrow your question down

Comment: Well is there any reason I shouldn't create a package name like that?

Comment: (i'm not the downvoter, fwiw) package names are _usually_ the domain of the website or the domain of the developer, i believe this is the standard followed, but it could be wrong

Comment: I understand that part, but if the domain name is the same as the app name, is that an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to create a package name like "com.moose.moose"?

If you own the `moose.com` domain, yes. You can use `com.moose` or `com.moose.moose` or `com.moose.moose.moooooooooooooooooooooooose` if you want, along with anything else that has `com.moose` in the first two segments.

If you do not own the `moose.com` domain, then I recommend that you use an application ID that is based off of a domain name that you own. Otherwise, the owners of `moose.com` could take issue with your application ID and cause trouble ([mynd you, møøse bites Kan be pretty nasti](http://www.smouse.force9.co.uk/monty.htm)).

Comment: Alright sweet, thank you!